# Python: multiple data types in a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, types

Using: Py3.X

Hi, i have a list as shown below, and i want to print it's field individually, May i know how can i store multiple data types into a variable.

Failed:

```
S = [1, 2, a, b]

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Success:

```
T = ['1','2','a','b']
print(T[1])
2
```

How to make 'S' into the format of 'T' that every field is saved with single quotes.
else how can i use 'S' list without putting those fields under single quotes.

required output:

```
print(S[1])
2
```

Comment: You need the quotes; `a` is a variable name, `'a'` is a string literal. `[1, 2, 'a', 'b']`.

Comment: You can't store a character without single quotes I.e, a is variable and 'a' is value.

Answer (score 1):

you either have to define a, or assign it as a string:

```
a = 3
l = [1,2,a]
print(l)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

OR

```
l = [1,2,'a']
print(l)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 'a']
```

your error is because you haven't assigned a value to a

Answer (score 0):

When we write:

```
var = 'a'    # This is string 'a'
```

`var` will store a reference to the `string 'a'`.

When we write:

```
var = a      # This is variable a
```

`var` will store a reference which the `variable a` is storing.

---

You can do something like this:

```
S = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']    # First two are integers and the last two are strings.
```